# Activity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView

Tags: java, android, xml

I am experiencing this error on this AddRestaurantActivity

This is my `AddRestaurantActivity.java` file. This is code for the activity which updates the database and creates a new restaurant with goggle geo places latitude and longitude. In the emulator when I press the Create button to create the restaurant the app dies (unfortunately Restaurant finder has stopped). And the error in the logcat is found underneath

```
 package admin;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
    import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.location.Address;
    import android.location.Geocoder;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import com.mad.restaurantfinderrm.R;
    import com.mad.restaurantfinderrm.library.DatabaseHandler;
    import com.mad.restaurantfinderrm.library.JSONParser;
    import com.mad.restaurantfinderrm.library.UserFunctions;

    public class AddRestaurantActivity extends Activity {

    UserFunctions userFunctions;

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    EditText inputName;
    EditText inputType;
    EditText inputBio;
    EditText inputAddressLine1;
    EditText inputAddressLine2;
    EditText inputAddressLine3;
    EditText inputContactNum;
    EditText inputEmail;
    EditText inputMenuUrl;

    // url to create new Restaurant

    // private static String url_create_restaurant =
    // "http://192.168.0.10/~robertmcnamara/RestaurantFinderAPI/createRestaurant.php";
    private static String url_create_restaurant = "http://askme-        jobs.com/api/createRestaurant.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

    static Double lat;
    static Double lng;

    // DB
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
    private Cursor mCursor;
    String user_id;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_restaurant);

        userFunctions = new UserFunctions();

        // getting user_id
        DatabaseHandler mh = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
        mDb = mh.getWritableDatabase();
        mCursor = mDb.query("login", null, null, null, null, null, null);

        if (mCursor != null && mCursor.getCount() > 0) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
            user_id = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("uid"));
        }

        // Edit Text
        inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
        inputType = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputType);
        inputBio = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputBio);
        inputAddressLine1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputAddress1);
        inputAddressLine2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputAddress2);
        inputAddressLine3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputAddress3);
        inputContactNum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputContactNum);
        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputEmail);
        inputMenuUrl = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputMenuUrl);

        // Create button
        Button btnCreateRestaurant = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCreateRestaurant);

        // button click event
        btnCreateRestaurant.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (inputName.getText().toString().trim().contentEquals("")
                        || inputType.getText().toString().trim()
                                .contentEquals("")
                        || inputBio.getText().toString().trim()
                                .contentEquals("")
                        || inputAddressLine1.getText().toString().trim()
                                .contentEquals("")
                        || inputAddressLine2.getText().toString().trim()
                                .contentEquals("")
                        || inputContactNum.getText().toString().trim()
                                .contentEquals("")
                        || inputEmail.getText().toString().trim()
                                .contentEquals("")
                        || inputMenuUrl.getText().toString().trim()
                                .contentEquals("")) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            AddRestaurantActivity.this);

                    // Setting Dialog Title
                    alertDialog.setTitle("Input validation");

                    // Setting Dialog Message
                    alertDialog
                            .setMessage("Please enter all details again,\nmaking sure they are correct");

                    // Setting Icon to Dialog
                    // alertDialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.delete);

                    // Setting Positive "Yes" Button
                    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });

                    // Showing Alert Message
                    alertDialog.show();
                } else {
                    // creating new product in background thread
                    new CreateNewRestaurant().execute();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /*
     * Event Handling for Individual menu item selected Identify single menu
     * item by it's id
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_logout:
            // logout user
            // TODO check Internet here?
            userFunctions.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
            Intent login = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    LoginActivity.class);
            login.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(login);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
            // Closing dashboard screen
            finish();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Create new Restaurant
     * */
    class CreateNewRestaurant extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AddRestaurantActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Creating Restaurant..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Creating Restaurant
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            String name = inputName.getText().toString();
            String type = inputType.getText().toString();
            String bio = inputBio.getText().toString();
            String addressLine1 = inputAddressLine1.getText().toString();
            String addressLine2 = inputAddressLine2.getText().toString();
            String addressLine3 = inputAddressLine3.getText().toString();
            String phoneNum = inputContactNum.getText().toString();
            String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
            String menuUrl = inputMenuUrl.getText().toString();

            // img
            // String img = "";

            String fullAddress = name + ", " + addressLine1 + ", "
                    + addressLine2 + ", " + addressLine3;
            Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext());
            List<Address> addressList;
            try {
                addressList = geoCoder.getFromLocationName(fullAddress, 1);
                Address address = addressList.get(0);
                if (address.hasLatitude() && address.hasLongitude()) {
                    lat = address.getLatitude();
                    lng = address.getLongitude();
                }
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            Log.v("LAT", lat.toString());
            Log.v("LNG", lng.toString());

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type", type));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("bio", bio));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("addressLine1", addressLine1));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("addressLine2", addressLine2));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("addressLine3", addressLine3));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("contactNumber", phoneNum));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat", lat.toString()));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lng", lng.toString()));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("url", menuUrl));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_id", user_id));
            // getting JSON Object
            // Note that create product url accepts POST method
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_restaurant,
                    "POST", params);

            // check for success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully created product
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            ViewRestaurantActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("MESSAGE", "add");
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(i);
                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_top,
                            R.anim.slide_out_bottom);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // failed to create product
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once done
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }

}
```

**Error in logcat :**

```
01-22 07:50:28.381: E/WindowManager(924): Activity com.mad.restaurantfinderrm.TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{41891c88 V.E..... R.....I. 0,0-240,147} that was originally added here
01-22 07:50:28.381: E/WindowManager(924): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.mad.restaurantfinderrm.TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{41891c88 V.E..... R.....I. 0,0-240,147} that was originally added here
01-22 07:50:28.381: E/WindowManager(924):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:345)
01-22 07:50:28.381: E/WindowManager(924):   at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:239)
01-22 07:50:28.381: E/WindowManager(924):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
01-22 07:50:28.381: E/WindowManager(924):   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
01-22 07:50:28.381: E/WindowManager(924):   at com.mad.restaurantfinderrm.Tab2Fragment.error(Tab2Fragment.java:248)
01-22 07:50:28.381: E/WindowManager(924):   at com.mad.restaurantfinderrm.Tab2Fragment.displayDeals(Tab2Fragment.java:324)
01-22 07:50:28.381: E/WindowManager(924):   at com.mad.restaurantfinderrm.Tab2Fragment$LoadDeals$1.run(Tab2Fragment.java:209)
01-22 07:50:28.381: E/WindowManager(924):   at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:4673)
01-22 07:50:28.381: E/WindowManager(924):   at com.mad.restaurantfinderrm.Tab2Fragment$LoadDeals.onPostExecute(Tab2Fragment.java:183)
01-22 07:50:28.381: E/WindowManager(924):   at com.mad.restaurantfinderrm.Tab2Fragment$LoadDeals.onPostExecute(Tab2Fragment.java:1)
01-22 07:50:28.381: E/WindowManager(924):   at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
01-22 07:50:28.381: E/WindowManager(924):   at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
01-22 07:50:28.381: E/WindowManager(924):   at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
01-22 07:50:28.381: E/WindowManager(924):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-22 07:50:28.381: E/WindowManager(924):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-22 07:50:28.381: E/WindowManager(924):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
01-22 07:50:28.381: E/WindowManager(924):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-22 07:50:28.381: E/WindowManager(924):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-22 07:50:28.381: E/WindowManager(924):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
01-22 07:50:28.381: E/WindowManager(924):   at             com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-22 07:50:28.381: E/WindowManager(924):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Did you try placing your dialog creation/dismiss inside an runOnUIThread?

Comment: The stacktrace says the leaked dialog is in `Tab2Fragment.error()` but you're not showing that code.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `finish()` before `onPostExecute` is called. I think this will leak your `pDialog`. Try moving `finish()` in the `onPostExecute` after dismissing the `pDialog`